# User defined variables within function "not found", can only set globally - why?

Tags: r, function, variables, for-loop

Currently how come my function says variable "n not found" when typing in the function:

```
 gamedata(1000,0.5,1000,50)
```

The function works if I type in the values manually, but I want the values to be user defined.

Any idea where I might be going wrong?

```
s = 100
outcome = matrix(0, s, 1)

n=1000
pr=0.5
m=100
q=50
l=30

for(i in 1:s){
gamedata = function(n,pr,m,q) {
turn = cumsum(2*rbinom(n,1,prob=pr)-1) 
gameover = which(turn == -l) 
winner = which(turn == q) 
if(length(gameover)==0){gameover=c(0)}
if(length(winner)==0){winner=c(0)}
if(gameover==0 && winner==0){turn[n]}else 
if(gameover[1]>winner[1]){-30}else{
q}
} 
outcome[i] = gamedata(n,pr,m,q)
if (i==s){
gameover.prob=sum(outcome == -l)/100
winner.prob=sum(outcome == q)/100
wingame.prob=sum(outcome > 0)/100
result=as.vector(outcome)
}
```

A little bit of insight into the code:
Each turn you can either win or lose, resulting in +1 or -1
If in n simulations the total goes to negative l, then the game ends
if in n simulations the total goes to q, then we can quit with that amount
if players neither wins or loses, add n-th value to the vector
otherwise add winner or gameover value to the vector, whichever comes first

Comment: Can you please recheck the code you uploaded? 1) What is spin2 object in the function? 2) do you really want to redefine the function on each iteration of the loop? 3) what is k?

Comment: I have updated the code with those two mistakes you pointed out.

Comment: Next, you should remove the `.` in `if(length(winner)==0){winner.=c(0)}` After that, the code runs for me just fine. Both in the loop and when values set manually...

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  Yes you are right! I changed that.I think the code runs ok now, its just all the values are determined outside the model.  How can I make it so that when I type gamedata(n,pr,m,q) and various values that I will return different probability values.  As currently I only uses the values I have listed at the top and it isn't included within the function.  That is the issue I am currently having.